# Feed streaming HTTP to Scala's XMLEventReader?

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing, http-streaming

Originally I was trying to use Java APIs for this, but now I am going to see if I can use Scala to parse XML documents coming through an XML stream. The following is a basic setup of `XMLEventReader`:

```
val reader = new xml.pull.XMLEventReader(IOSource)
while (reader.hasNext) System.out.println(reader.next)
```

The problem is `IOSource` must be a form of `scala.io.Source` and I'm only seeing local file methods for such parsing. What native Scala APIs can I use to feed XML coming from streaming HTTP to the event reader?

Thanks!

### Edit

Looks like a Java API is going to be necessary. So instead, is it possible to convert a Java `InputStream` into a Scala `io.Source`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scala 2.10.2 standard library `scala.io.Source`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source%24) (you want [`object Source`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source%24), not [`abstract class Source`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source)) offers a number of `from*` methods, including `fromInputStream` and `fromURL`.

Scala 2.9.X is, if I recall, similar if not the same.